# Mootools form validation fails in IE8 compatibility view

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, mootools

I've created a form ([form website page](http://www.mutuelle-de-sante.eu)) that works perfectly on IE8, Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and SeaMonkey but not when I'm using the compatibilty view to emulate IE7.

When using the compatibility view to emulate IE7 the form can be sent with all fields empty which is not allowed (the fields have the class validate['required']).

Compatibility View Screenshot:

[image: Compatibility View Screenshot]

I really have no idea of how to correct this and I'm wondering if you guys have already met a similar situation and how you solved it.

Comment: You need to show some code, and preferably also a link to the site (I can see it in your screenshot, so you might as well add it to the question).

Comment: @thirtydot The link to the page is in my post. I can put the code on jsfiddle but the code is quite long and you have direct access to it with the source code of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution : the problem was that I had a form inside a div element and both had the same name (and the name and id of the form were the same) which was confusing for the browser. I guess they've resolved that issue since IE8.